# I have two data frames stating different features of two objects and I want to combine them to make one dataframe having a comparison of both

Tags: r, merge, comparison

I have the following data.frames (code below)

```
  Fruit     Apple                                                
1 countries Germany,Austria,Netherlands, USA
2 varieties A,B,C
```

and

```
  Fruit     Banana                                                             
1 countries Poland,Germany,France,Netherlands, UK
2 varieties N,C,A
```

I want to merge them into:

```
   Col1      Col2        Banana Apple
 1 countries Poland           1     0
 2 countries Germany          1     1
 3 countries France           1     0
 4 countries Netherlands      1     1
 5 countries UK               1     0
 6 countries Austria          0     1
 7 countries USA              0     1
 8 varieties A                1     1
 9 varieties B                0     1
10 varieties C                1     1
11 varieties N                1     0
```

Here is the code for the two data frames and the expected results:

```
 c<-structure(list(Fruit = c("countries", "varieties"), Apple = c("Germany,Austria,Netherlands, USA", 
                                                                     "A,B,C")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                  "data.frame"))


d<-structure(list(Fruit = c("countries", "varieties"), Banana = c("Poland,Germany,France,Netherlands, UK", 
                                                                  "N,C,A")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                               "data.frame"))

 Result<-structure(list(Col1 = c("countries", "countries", "countries", 
"countries", "countries", "countries", "countries", "varieties", 
"varieties", "varieties", "varieties"), Col2 = c("Poland", "Germany", 
"France", "Netherlands", "UK", "Austria", "USA", "A", "B", "C", 
"N"), Banana = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), Apple = c(0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Edit: I have been able to merge the two data frames like the way I wanted.
The code is a bit sloppy but it works.

```
c<-separate_rows(c, Apple , convert = TRUE)
c<- c%>% mutate(P_Apple=1)

d<-separate_rows(d, Banana , convert = TRUE)
d<- d%>% mutate(P_Banana=1)

Result<-full_join (c,d, by=c("Apple"="Banana"))

Result<-Result%>% mutate(Fruit=case_when(
  is.na(Fruit.x)~Fruit.y,
  !is.na(Fruit.x)~Fruit.x )) %>% select(c("Fruit","Apple","P_Apple","P_Banana")) %>%rename(Features="Fruit",Fruit="Apple")

Result[is.na(Result)]<-0
```

Comment: Are you sure about the output? First row shouldn't be `1` for `banana`and `0` for `apple`? Same for other rows.

Comment: @RLave: Thank You for pointing out. You are right!

Comment: You should consider not completely merging the 2 data.frames. For most (all?) use cases, it will be better to have one table with the country information and one table with the variety information. Your suggested result does not make semantic sense.

Comment: Looking more at your data, I think you could have loaded it better. This looks like a table with columns `attribute` and `value`. `Fruit` and `Apple` should probably be rows in that table and not headers. I am quite curious to know where this data comes from and whether you could extract it better to begin with.

Comment: @antoine-sac Thank you for suggestions regarding editing. Also, unfortunately I need the information in the order I have suggested. Also, the data was provided to me in this format itself. It is report generated from oracle database and exported to excel. I have managed to merge these two data finally :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below the required output. Let me know if you need any additions.

```
library(dummies)
library(splitstackshape)
library(tibble)

#Your Data

c<-structure(list(Fruit = c("countries", "varieties"), Apple = c("Germany,Austria,Netherlands, USA", 
                                                                 "A,B,C")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                              "data.frame"))


d<-structure(list(Fruit = c("countries", "varieties"), Banana = c("Poland,Germany,France,Netherlands, UK", 
                                                                  "N,C,A")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                               "data.frame"))


#Transform the two data frames and rbind

e = data.frame(t(c),stringsAsFactors = F) %>% tibble::rownames_to_column()
names(e) = as.character(e[1,]);e = e[-1,]
f = data.frame(t(d),stringsAsFactors = F) %>% tibble::rownames_to_column()
names(f) = as.character(f[1,]);f = f[-1,]

g = data.frame(t(cSplit(rbind(e,f), c("countries","varieties"), sep=",", direction = "wide")),stringsAsFactors = F) %>% tibble::rownames_to_column()
names(g) = as.character(g[1,]);g = g[-1,]

#Removing leading spaces for UK and USA
unique_countries = gsub("^\\s+","",unlist(strsplit(rbind(e,f)$countries,",")))

cmatrix  = g %>% select(-Fruit) %>% filter_all(any_vars(!is.na(.))) %>% dummy.data.frame(.,sep = "_") %>% t() %>% 
  data.frame(.,stringsAsFactors = F) %>% tibble::rownames_to_column() %>%
  separate(rowname,c("Fruit","Category"),"_") %>% select(Fruit,Category) %>%
  mutate(Flag = 1) %>% spread(Fruit,Flag) %>% na.fill(0) %>% data.frame(.,stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
  filter(!Category == "NA") %>%
  mutate(Parent_category = ifelse(Category %in% unique_countries,"countries","varieties"))


#And the Output
> cmatrix
      Category Apple Banana Parent_category
1            A     1      1       varieties
2      Austria     1      0       countries
3            B     1      0       varieties
4            C     1      1       varieties
5       France     0      1       countries
6      Germany     1      1       countries
7            N     0      1       varieties
8  Netherlands     1      1       countries
9       Poland     0      1       countries
10          UK     0      1       countries
11         USA     1      0       countries
```